# How to handle hash nested keys validation in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activemodel

I currently have a model in which I want to use dot notation to add errors to be more specific about which key in the hash attribute is faulty:

```
class MyFormObject
  include ActiveModel::Validations
  include ActiveModel::AttributeAssignment

  attr_accessor :name, :metadata

  validates :name, presence: true 
  validate address_is_present_in_metadata

  def initialize(**attributes)
    assign_attributes(attributes)
  end

  def validate_address_is_present_in_metadata
    errors.add("metadata.address", "can't be blank") if metadata[:address].blank?
  end
end
```

This works, but if I decide to use a symbol instead of a message like the following:

```
errors.add("metadata.address", :blank) if metadata[:address].blank?
```

then Rails complains because `metadata.address` is not an attribute. The  `ActiveModel::Errors` code that throws the error checks if the attribute is `:base` and if it's not, it tries to read the attribute from the model to generate the error message... and boom.

```
value = attribute != :base ? @base.send(:read_attribute_for_validation, attribute) : nil)
```

As a workaround, I decided to override `read_attribute_for_validation`.

```
def read_attribute_for_validation(key)
  key_str = key.to_s
  return public_send(key) unless key_str.include?(".")

  key_path = key_str.split(".").map(&:to_sym)
  public_send(key_path.first).dig(*key_path[1, key_path.size])
end
```

Is there a better/supported way to validate nested keys in a hash that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://www.rubydoc.info/docs/rails/ActiveModel/Validations:read_attribute_for_validation) :

> By default this is assumed to be an instance named after the
>   attribute. Override this method in subclasses should you need to
>   retrieve the value for a given attribute differently.

So it seems that your strategy is valid.

Some advices though :

- you could use [`public_send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Object.html#method-i-public_send) instead of `send`
- nesting has another [meaning](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Module.html#method-c-nesting), you could use another variable name
- [`Array#[a,b]`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-slice) takes `b` elements starting at `a`, so `b` shouldn't be bigger than `Array#size`. You could just use `array.drop(1)`. You might have been looking for `array[a..b]`, which takes elements between indices `a` and `b`.

Comment: Indeed it seems to map exactly to my use case, also thanks for the code review